# Issue adding a Listener of Type ComponentEventListener < ComponentValueChangeEvent >

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a vaadin select. I added a change value listener to it, inside of it I invoke fireEvent.

In another class a VerticalLayout view, I tried to add a listener but I cannot I understand the parameters of the method.

```
Class<T> eventType, ComponentEventListener<T> listener
```

evenType in my case is: ComponentValueChangeEvent but the 2nd parameter the listener is what I am facing issue with. It is a listener type.

```
addListener(ComponentValueChangeEvent.class, listener);
```

This my Select where I invoke fireEvent

```
themeSelect.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
            ThemeList themeList = UI.getCurrent().getElement().getThemeList();   
            fireEvent(event);
            if ("Dark".equals(event.getValue())) {
                themeList.add(Lumo.DARK);
                fireEvent(event);
            } else {
                themeList.remove(Lumo.DARK);

            }
        });
```

I am using Vaadin 14.9.5 .

How can I add an event listener to my VerticalLayout.

I tried to use add detach listener but I don't think it works.

I tried lambda expression suggested by IDE Netbeans. but I didn't work.

```
addListener(ComponentValueChangeEvent.class,new ComponentEventListener<ComponentValueChangeEvent>() {
       
            @Override
            public void onComponentEvent(ComponentValueChangeEvent event) {
 
            }
        });
```

Doing this will give this compilation Error:
incompatible types: cannot infer functional interface descriptor for com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener<com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractField.ComponentValueChangeEvent>

but I see ComponentValueChangeEvent **dose** extend ComponentEvent.See the docs below.

Docs:

ComponentEventListener :
https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.10.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentEventListener.html

addListener:
https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.10.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html#addListener-java.lang.Class-com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener-

Comment: Why you are firing the event, what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want some component in another class to reflect the changes in the select component . In my case it is a change in theme. The component has a listener but I don't know a way of notifying the component of the change or event,